# App permissions to access hardware "at any time without your confirmation"

Tags: android, permissions

On Android applications now some applications say that they want access to things such as speaker or camera "at any time without your confirmation".

I wasn't sure if this meant that it does not require your overt permission each time to access that resource, or if it meant that it can literally access that resource whenever it wants.

I'm not quite sure what to make of it and it seems like a clear security violation if apps can be given such access. What are peoples thoughts on this issue or does anyone know exactly what these permissions actually mean?

Comment: Android and Apple do a fairly good job of keeping malware out of their app stores, but yes, apps have pretty much free reign over your phone. No one particularly likes it, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the eprmission means just as what you think it means.
it may use the systems at anytime it wants to, so it can activate the camera anytime it wants too.

what i think of it? well, here in europe, privacydoesnt get as violated as in the USA when it comes to telecomunication and technology.

not saying we dont get it, but the USA laws on that area are not only smoother, but also more unfair